# Why do unicorn prefer a woman's touch to a man's?

Tags: harry-potter, magical-creatures, unicorns

In *Goblet of Fire*, Professor Grubbly-Plank indicates that unicorns prefer a woman's touch to a man's:

> “Boys keep back!” barked Professor Grubbly-Plank, throwing out an arm and catching Harry hard in the chest. “They prefer the woman’s touch, unicorns. Girls to the front, and approach with care, come on, easy does it…”

What would happen if a man were to touch a Unicorn, or a Unicorn willingly touched a man?

Comment: Because they're afraid the man will steal their Unicoins?

Comment: Not a HP answer, but it's common unicorn lore that they're more comfortable with women (virgins in particular)

Comment: I may have ruined it for everyone, by drinking the blood of so many unicorns. Sorry everybody.

Comment: @BrianS If we go out of HP,there are some evidences that a king having a Unicorn.In Chronicles of Narnia ,the king Peter's horse was Unicorn.

Comment: The unicorn's status as something that can only be captured by a maiden was well-established in the Middle Ages (a quick internet search finds a number of artworks to that effect from the period, such as the 15th century tapestry Maiden with Unicorn). That doesn't mean an individual author can't write the myth differently, but it does mean that Lewis is outside the norm for unicorn myth.

Comment: Apparently, men causing more stress to animals may have a basis in actual science. http://arstechnica.com/science/2014/04/mice-get-stressed-out-feel-less-pain-when-male-lab-workers-are-present/

Comment: @alexwlchan Good link..But how can we compare Mice and Unicorn..

Comment: @Mani: We can’t really, but I thought it was an interesting data point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While a unicorn prefers witches to wizards, they tend to prefer to eschew human contact entirely. From the entry for “unicorn” in *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them*:

> It generally avoids human contact, is more likely to allow a witch to approach it than a wizard, and is so fleet of foot that it is very difficult to capture.

In *Philosopher’s Stone*, when Harry et al. are trying to find the unicorn killer in the Forbidden Forest, Hagrid makes another remark about their speed:

> “*Could* a werewolf be killing the unicorns?” Harry asked.
>
> “Not fast enough,” said Hagrid. “It’s not easy ter catch a unicorn,
> they’re powerful magic creatures. I never knew one ter be hurt before.”

So if somebody tried to approach a unicorn, and the unicorn was uncomfortable, then it would probably run away before they could get close.

I suspect the converse (a unicorn approaching a human) is unlikely, unless the human has already shown that they want to get closer to the unicorn.

As for why unicorns prefer witches to wizards: canon doesn’t say. It’s probably related to the common belief that women are gentler than men (and therefore less likely to pose a threat to the unicorn), but I don’t have anything to back that up.

Comment: I guess the founders thought girls were more trustworthy.

Comment: @b_jonas: The founders? Who “founded” unicorns?

Comment: @alexwlchan: I was kidding.  Hermione says something like this in *Prisoner* about why boys are magically not allowed in the Gryffindor girls' dormitory, whereas girls are allowed in the boys' dormitory.  Founders refers to the four founding wizards of Hogwarts.

Comment: I think "The founders" were not related to Unicorns in this..

Comment: @alexwlchan So the unicorns believe that the men cause harm to their kind.

Comment: @Mani: That seems consistent with traditional literature about unicorns, and lacking anything to contradict that in HP canon, that’s probably right.

Comment: @alexwlchan I have seen now that they allow only virgin to touch them,making sense that it might be a characteristic of Unicorn.